# Why can't publish posts with too much text?

Tags: posts, editor

I'm trying to publish a posts in my WordPress, but when cointain too much words save but doesn't save the content of description like example.
I need take the information inside a file and save it in my DB, but when I press publish or update, the request is send it, but when the page reload, show all the other fields but not the description, when I'm sending around 5 millions of words or even more. How I'm using a script to take the content of a file, my files are around 1mb until 20mb, just text with somes styles.
In the DB I'm using longtext as value until I know that support 4Gb, so I don't understand why the posts can save the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you look into LONGTEXT [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-type-overview.html) you'll see that:

> The effective maximum length of LONGTEXT columns also depends on the
>   configured maximum packet size in the client/server protocol and
>   available memory.

So I would say that 4GB support is only theoretical, in real life your server configuration wouldn't allow operating on such a big chunk of data in one DB field, especially if it's a shared hosting solution.

Comment: ok, thanks you, I'm testing in local machine, so going to check this.

Answer (score 0):

there is a setting in wordpress named post_max_size which disallow it.
try this on yor config file to overwrite it:

```
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
```

64 should work for you, you can incressed even further, if your server allows it.